# Nowhere-differentiable function via Fourier-Series

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Consider the function formally defined by
$$f_\alpha(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^\alpha}\sin (k^\alpha x).$$
For example, $f_1(x)$ is the $2\pi$-periodic extension of
$$
x\mapsto \begin{cases}\hfill\frac{1}{2}(\pi-x),&\text{if }x\in[0,\pi]\\
\hfill -\frac12(\pi+x),&\text{if }x\in(-\pi,0)\end{cases}.
$$
and obviously $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to\infty}f_\alpha(x) = \sin(x)$. It seems like e.g. $f_2(x)$ is an example of a nowhere differentiable function. So here's my question: How do I prove this and for what values of $\alpha$ is this true?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to think it's nowhere differentiable? Standard results say it's certainly _almost nowhere_ differentiable, but it seems sort of borderline for nowhere differentiability. (No, I  haven't proved anything here...)

Comment: Since it looked familar, I check my old copy of Bartle's *The Elements of Real Analysis*, but it offers $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\cos\left(3^kx\right)$$ as an example of a continuous nowhere-differentiable function. Though he just refers "the reader to the books of Titchmarsh and Boas for further details and reference."

Comment: My only guess comes from the divergence of the series of the "formal derivative" of the function but I know that this doesn't imply anything. In the series given by @PaulSinclair, as in the Weierstrass functions, the terms are always exponential in $k$ and I wonder if a power of $k$ is enough to make differentiability fail... I would also be happy to have an answer if my series was replaced by $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(k^\beta x)}{k^\alpha}$$ for some $\beta>\alpha$...